# Use same model classes (DTO) between flutter and the native code

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin, dart

By now we have 2 android apps, one invokes the other one (directional relation). The first passes data via intent, by the compiled and published to our nexus repository model, written in kotlin (serialized to json).

Now, we want to migrate the second (invoked) app to the flutter, and still have the shared model. My question is - is it possible to use kotlin DTOs to the flutter (so far I see that the method channel does not allow for custom classes), or even better - to compile dart package to jar, and use it in the native code? In the first case I think about something like typescript definition files used when you use ts and js in one project.

Comment: It might be worth looking at how pigeon generates method channel code. Also consider some wire format like protobuf that you could maybe use in Dart and native. (Note that you would just pass the wire format over the method channel as bytes and you can therefore pass anything that protobuf can handle.)

Comment: So you suggest to let the current model just be, and make internal (in app) another model, based on the the protobuf and byte stream?

Comment: Or, if you are already using JSON as the serialized format, you could use that over the method channel, but you would have to port the DTOs to Dart and Swift to allow the serialization/deserialization there.

Comment: So there is no direct solution to compile native library (jar for example) from dart?

Comment: No, none at all. Dart compiles to its VM, or native (AOT - requires the Dart runtime) or Javascript.